# ¿Cómo mostrar el último termino de la secuencia de fibonacci en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Buen día a todos!
Me piden realizar una función donde muestre la secuencia fibonacci y cual es su último número y otra función donde muestre el número anterior y el siguiente número. Ejemplo: si es 5 el anterior seria 3 y el siguiente 8. La cuestión es que cuando pongo un número menor a 3 me regresa el último numero como arreglo vacío. De lo demás corre bien. Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias.

**Código**

```
let primerTermino  = 0;
let segundoTermino = 1;   
let resultado = []
            
function fibonacci(numeroFibonacci) {
  let fibb = [0, 1];
            
  for(let i = 2; i < numeroFibonacci; i++) {
    fibb[i] = fibb[i - 1] + fibb[i - 2]
    resultado = fibb[i]  
                
    primerTermino = segundoTermino;
    segundoTermino =  resultado;
  }
        
console.log("Secuencia: ", fibb, "fibb")
console.log("El último termino es:", resultado)
}   
    
function fibonacciConcat(numeroConcat) {
    let fibb =[0, 1];
    fibonacci(numeroConcat)
    
    if(resultado < fibb ){
      resultado = segundoTermino
    
      if( fibb < numeroConcat ){
        primerTermino = resultado  
        
      }else {
        segundoTermino = primerTermino + resultado
        
        if(fibb === numeroConcat) {
        segundoTermino = resultado + primerTermino
      }
    } 
    
  }
    
  console.log("Número anterior:", primerTermino)
  console.log("Siguiente número:", segundoTermino) 
}
fibonacciConcat(2)
fibonacci(8)
```

Comment: Ahí  probando aqui `for(let i = 2; i < numeroFibonacci; i++)` le agregue un `=` o sea `for(let i = 2; i <= numeroFibonacci; i++)` y me tiro como ultimo termino el 1 ingresando 2 como parametro.

Comment: Ya quedo, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

Cambiar `<` por `<=`

```
function fibonacci(numeroFibonacci) {
  let fibb = [0, 1];
            
  for(let i = 2; i <= numeroFibonacci; i++) { 
    fibb[i] = fibb[i - 1] + fibb[i - 2]
    resultado = fibb[i]  
                
    primerTermino = segundoTermino;
    segundoTermino =  resultado;
  }
```

Aqui `for(let i = 2; i <` vas a iterar de 2 en 2 y pusiste que la iteracion se terminana si `i` ***(es 2)*** es menor que `numeroFibonacci` ***(es 2)*** adjunto una imagen de ejemplo para comprender mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como esto `2 < 2` es **false** no iba a entrar al ciclo mientras que con la otra evaluación que es **true** entra si es menor que 2 o si por lo menos es igual a 2.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora entiendo cual era el error.

Comment: Bueno, de nada!